# can we initialise different version of tiny mce for a single text box?

Tags: tinymce

I want to create two instances of tiny mce which will have two different set of buttons. I'm trying to initialize both conditionally for a single text area. But, by default it takes the first inti set. am I right or wrong ? Help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem will be that you can have only one tinymce instance globaly running. There might be a workaround for that, but i never saw one. The id of your textarea will be the id of your initialized editor. So you can have only one editor with one id - means only one tinymce instance with one editor for one textarea.